# iphone app that recognises colour

Tags: iphone

Can you give me a starter point for creating an iphone app that recognises colour. I have seen this app http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/2f83a363-2fce-4107-8394-27feb3645fff and it would be excellent to be able to find out the technique used for the colour recognition part. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to display a `UIImagePickerController` with it's source type set to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`. Once the user snaps a photo, you can then get a `CGImage` of the photo taken, and look for the color info that way. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics) might help you with figuring out the color info you want.

Comment: I think that it would need to be recognition from the video camera on the phone, although thanks for the info there. I'll follow them up.